# wxPython find a searcher to listctrl

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, search

I have a situation that I am not being able to resolve in my project. The question is that I am developing a list manager for repairs, I have everything set up and actually working, I am just racking my brain trying to put together an interactive search engine that searches, excuse me, for matches of wx.searchctrl in the set list of wx .listctrl. What occurred to me to solve it momentarily is that when I find matches I paint them a certain color, although it is not so practical, this is what I could... I leave the code
Could you guide me on how to do so that when entering keys in the search engine it searches for the matches, deletes the non-matching items and displays the matches in the wx.listctrl (which also after deleting the searchctrl string restores the list to how it was)? I didn't come across any information about it! Thank you all

"""def buscarLista(self, e): search_text = self.buscador.GetValue().lower()

```
for i in range(self.cajaL.GetItemCount()):

    item_text = self.cajaL.GetItemText(i).lower()

    if search_text and search_text in item_text:

        self.cajaL.SetItemBackgroundColour(i, wx.Colour(0, 0, 255))

        items_coincidentes.append(i)

    else:

        self.cajaL.SetItemBackgroundColour(i, wx.Colour(0, 0, 0))

        items_no_coincidentes.append(i)"""
```